# SQL Server - Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_XX_XXXXX’ and constraint not found

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

We have application where API communicate with SQL Server database and get & set data thru stored procedure.

While saving data in production server, we are getting error (Custom error handling) in application as follows
‘Data for below tabs are not saved successfully, please review data and save
Dynamic : Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_XX_XXXXXX’

Now to check the issue, we were searching for given constrain name in database using below, but surprisingly, we do not found any such constraint, so now how to identify the table which causes this error

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,
OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName,
type_desc AS ConstraintType
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE type_desc IN ('PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT')
order by 1
```

Is there any way to get the table name linked to given primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was issue with how application shows error text, somehow it was truncated and only half of the constraint name was displayed.

Client gave specific scenario to reproduce the error and then i found the exact table name and its primary key name.

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views...

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE 
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'PK_XX_XXXXXX'
```

Comment: It's a `VIEW` not a table

Comment: This is a great example of why a constraint is a first-class object.

Comment: Hello Allumeraz, 
Thanks for your reply, no table found with given primary constraint name

Comment: Hello Nicomp,
Can you please explain more on this "This is a great example of why a constraint is a first-class object" ?

Comment: Hi Manish, can you post the Stored Procedure code? Could it be a table variable in the procedure with a Primary Key defined on it?

Comment: Hello Allumeraz,
Thanks for your reply, i generated script of DB and search for given primary key, not found